# How to overclock Intel Pentium III 450 MhZ?

Tags: overclocking, intel-pentium

**I hope this will help:**

```
Number of cores     1 (max 1)
Number of threads   1 (max 1)
Name            Intel Pentium III
Codename        Katmai
Specification       
Package (platform ID)   Slot 1 SECC2 (0x0)
CPUID           6.7.3
Extended CPUID      6.7
Core Stepping       kC0
Technology      0.25 um
Core Speed      448.6 MHz
Multiplier x FSB    4.5 x 99.7 MHz
Stock frequency     450 MHz
Instructions sets   MMX, SSE
L1 Data cache       16 KBytes, 4-way set associative, 32-byte line size
L1 Instruction cache    16 KBytes, 4-way set associative, 32-byte line size
L2 cache        512 KBytes, 4-way set associative, 32-byte line size
FID/VID Control     no
```

My motherboard is SIEMENS AG D1107 and this is my processor:

[image: img_1]
[image: img_2]

My BIOS is very old (Phoenix 07/05/99) so no way I can change the FSB settings from it.

I'm going to buy a new processor but until I haven`t got my hands on a new one, I want to overclock current.

I would be pleased if someone responds.

Comment: considering the sheer age of the system, any performance benefits are going to be negligible. Its a little like strapping fireworks to an old donkey to make it go faster. You're likely to get better results using the system with an OS that will run well with something that slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pentium III processors were multiplier locked & the only way to overclock them was to increase the FSB. If you can't increase the FSB, then you can't overclock them.

Comment: You'll need to find an updated BIOS. Can't find it anywhere, unfortunately

Comment: Not true! I used to have a 500MHz Intel Pentium III which ran Windows 98. Later when Windows XP got and I installed it, it was very slow. So what do I do? I increase the clock speed to 1 GHz without increasing the multiplier (I had played with it before), so on my next reboot, bam! Couldn't resurrect that processor back. Still miss it! This was in Probably in 2002-03.